# Spring-Boot Generic Constructor Injection Custom

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, dependency-injection, service

```
public abstract class BaseController<E,DTO> {

    protected final BaseService<E,DTO> service;

   public BaseController(final BaseService<E,DTO> service) {
       this.service = service;
   }
   // code ....
}


public class CarController extends BaseController<Car, CarDto> {

   public CarController(final CarService service) {
      super(service);
   }
   // code ...
}

@Service
public class CarService extends BaseService<Car, CarDto> {

   // code .... 
   //custom method
   public String getName(){
      return "Car Sevice";
  }
}
```

Spring-boot generic method develop. Service created in constructor. There is no problem working properly. Problem is custom method of service. Because service extends BaseService and see all base services methods but, it is custom services as CarService. Intellij give error

```
service.getname();
```

how can i solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

your service is type of BaseService, not CarService.

When you write something like `BaseService service = new CarService()` you can't access methods of CarService because your variable is BaseService type.

you would need to change service to be type of generic, same as you did with entity and dto.

```
public abstract class BaseController<E,DTO, S extends BaseService> {

    protected final  S  service;

    public BaseController(S service) {
        this.service = service;
    }
    // code ....
}


public class CarController extends BaseController<Car, CarDto, CarService> {

     public CarController(final CarService service) {
        super(service);
        service.getName();
    }
    // code ...
}
```

The `extends BaseService` in BaseController is only required if you would like to use any methods of BaseService in BaseController, like for example:

```
public abstract class BaseController<E,DTO, S extends BaseService> {

    protected final  S  service;

    public BaseController(S service) {
        this.service = service;
        service.doSomething();
        service.overrideMe();
    }
    // code ....
}

public class CarController extends BaseController<Car, CarDto, CarService> {

    public CarController(final CarService service) {
        super(service);
        service.getName();
        service.overrideMe();
        service.doSomething();
    }
    // code ...
}

public abstract class BaseService<E, DTO> {
    public abstract void overrideMe();
    
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("hi");
    }
}

@Service
public class CarService extends BaseService<Car, CarDto> {

    // code ....
    //custom method
    public String getName(){
        return "Car Sevice";
    }

    @Override
    public void overrideMe() {
        System.out.println("Overrided");
    }
}
```

If your BaseController doesn't need to know that S is extending BaseService (you won't call any methods of BaseService in BaseController) you can delete `extends BaseService` part

```
public abstract class BaseController<E,DTO, S> {

    protected final S service;

    public BaseController(S service) {
        this.service = service;
    }
    // code ....
}


public class CarController extends BaseController<Car, CarDto, CarService> {

    public CarController(final CarService service) {
        super(service);
        service.getName();
        service.overrideMe();
        service.doSomething();
    }
    // code ...
}

public abstract class BaseService<E, DTO> {
    public abstract void overrideMe();

    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("hi");
    }
}

public class CarService extends BaseService<Car, CarDto> {

    // code ....
    //custom method
    public String getName(){
        return "Car Sevice";
    }

    @Override
    public void overrideMe() {
        System.out.println("Overrided");
    }
}
```

Also think if you need E and DTO in BaseController